# Error Using Chrome Driver - Uncaught ReferenceError: showDate is not defined

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am using chrome driver version `89.0.4389.23` and my chrome browser version is `89.0.4389.90`. I had a perfectly running code as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.nccpl.com.pk/en/market-information/fipi-lipi/fipi-sector-wise')
```

At last line of code mentioned above I am getting an error `"Uncaught ReferenceError: showDate is not defined", source: https://www.nccpl.com.pk/en/portfolio-investments/fipi-sector-wise (1652)` I am unable to interpret this error and figure out what is wrong.

I am looking for an interpretation to this error and how can I fix it.

Comment: I cannot repro this with same browser + driver Is that 1652 coming back in stack trace?

Comment: @QHarr have you used the similar webpage? 1652 is coming when I execute last line of above mentioned code. Though I am able to scrape but this error seems to be there. Also if you go to webpage through browser and inspect page you will get this error in `console`

Comment: Looks like a website problem where indeed it is not defined `$('#inlineDatepicker').datepick({onSelect: showDate});` - called here. Is there an option to ignore such errors you can apply? It does not trip my page from loading successfully however so perhaps add exception handling if  a problem for you?